Enable new Set methods on TypeScript
New JavaScript Set methods landed in Chrome 122 (February 2024, read more here) and TypeScript announced support for them in v5.5 rc, so why does TypeScript complain Property 'difference' does not exist on type 'Set<string>'.(2339) when using v5.5.1-rc?
Playground
Runtime works as expected, but TypeScript complains.
tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [],
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ESNext","DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
  }
}

What am I missing?

In your playground it's because you're targeting ES2017; fix that and it works: https://tsplay.dev/mA0YPN

wow thanks, but in my local vscode i still get his error even though my tsconfig targets ESNext, any ideas why?

"…TypeScript complains": What exactly does this mean? What is the exact error message and where is it displayed? If the diagnostic is in VS Code's IntelliSense, then I suspect this question is a duplicate of What TypeScript version is Visual Studio Code using? How to update it?

yup this was the issue. i just needed to manually select the 5.5.1-rc version in vs-code.

@jsejcksn I don't see how it can be a duplicate since it doesn't even specify what IDE if any is used.

^ @AluanHaddad The asker both mentioned VS Code in a comment and confirmed the duplicate in a separate comment before I marked it as such. Did you find something about those unclear?

This should not have been re-opened. Voting to re-close as a duplicate of What TypeScript version is Visual Studio Code using? How to update it?

the question itself contain relevant information about how to Enable new Set methods on TypeScript, so it does not really a duplicate.
